# New bathtub isn't square

Tags: bathroom

Im trying to install a tub in a new 60 x 30 inch alcove. The tub is fitting in and is flush with the existing wall but now I'm not sure how to make the transition between the wall which would be painted, the side of the tub and the tile surround. Second issue is that the new tub is not square, It is flush at the top but out and proud of the wall by 3/4 of an inch at the bottom. I sent an email to American standard to see if that's normal but have not heard back. [image]

Comment: I'm sure there are tub designs where the front slopes out like that, but this should be made clear in the tub's spec sheet.

Comment: What are your finishes in the tub and wall?

Comment: No mention in the spec sheet but I have an email in to American std to see what they say. I installed same tub in another bathroom 2 years back and it seemed ( and currently looks) vertically square.  Separate shower going in so tile three sides not to the ceiling and the facing wall painted. If the tub was square I was thinking there might be a schluter profile that could make the transition between painted wall and tub.

Comment: Check the rough-in dimensions on the spec sheet. I am supposing your opening is a bit shallower than called for.

Comment: Is the tub level? Is your house square?

Comment: calls for 30 1/4 inch which is what I have.  ub is level walls are as well. If the tube was square I'd be ok.

Comment: We typically frame 2" minimium deeper than the tub rough in depth.  That is we design a 32" depth for a 30" tub or shower pan.  We do this to alleviate the exact issue you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Take it back as defective if it's not to stated specs. Trying to wedge the bottom flush until the floor goes in could crack the finish, if it's just bent out & not actually braced out. If the back wall isn't load bearing, you can plane or cut those studs back, plumbing re-alignment shouldn't be a big deal. Or, add another drywall layer to the foreground wall & make up the remainder with the tile layer. Or. just add tile edging with an ogee type edge.